# How to SSO Disqus in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, disqus

in my project I have this API [Disqus - ios](https://github.com/moqod/disqus-ios). I would be grateful if you could get an example of how to make and use SSO login. I current use Disqus login form (website) in this API.